# How do I get a specific substring for different cases

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to fetch the username *chunk* out of string that looks like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> Lines  = new List<string>()
            {
                "[20:03:01 INFO]: UUID of player MyUsername123 is b87e1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8659de8b4",
                "[21:03:10 INFO]: UUID of player Cool_Username is b7ecbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652f9de8b4",
                "[22:23:10 INFO]: UUID of player theuserN4m3 is b87eabc-c67c-4026-a359-8652ad9dssdse8b4",
                "[20:08:10 INFO]: UUID of player WhatANiceUsername is b87g1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652agde8b4",

            };

            foreach (var line in Lines)
            {
                //Get the username part
            }
        }
```

The usernames would be `MyUsername123`, `Cool_Username`, `theuserN4m3`, `WhatANiceUsername`

What's the best way of fetching these names?
I thought about regex but I don't know if that's resource heavy, and then about subscring but I wasn't sre on how to get that specific part starting at what index ending where because all usernames can have different lengths.

Comment: Is the username always in that same part of the string?

Comment: Is the first example actually missing the *is* part of "player XYZ is ..."? Or is that a typo?

Comment: The username is always in the same place and that was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a string split by space the containing array index 5 will contain the username.

```
public void SplitExample()
{
    List<string> Lines = new List<string>()
    {
       "[20:03:01 INFO]: UUID of player MyUsername123 is b87e1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8659de8b4",
       "[21:03:10 INFO]: UUID of player Cool_Username is b7ecbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652f9de8b4",
       "[22:23:10 INFO]: UUID of player theuserN4m3 is b87eabc-c67c-4026-a359-8652ad9dssdse8b4",
       "[20:08:10 INFO]: UUID of player WhatANiceUsername is b87g1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652agde8b4",
    };

    foreach(var i in Lines)
    {
       var splitArray = i.Split(' ');
       Console.WriteLine(splitArray[5]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea, I had something like that in mind but I couldnt think of that, I'll try that!

Comment: yeah nice idea, and it actually will be in 6th (index 5)

Answer (score 4):

I'd split the string at `space` characters, then grab the index of the username field (since you said it'd always be in the same spot).

```
foreach (var line in Lines)
{
    string[] trimmed = line.Split(' ');
    string username = trimmed[5];
}
```

You'd probably want to do a little better with error handling, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

A string is essentially an `IEnumerable<char>` so instead of using split you could use a little Linq. We know that the username starts at a fixed position and that spaces are not allowed in the username. With that knowledge the only unknown is how long the username is. We can use the `Skip()` and `TakeWhile()` extension methods in Linq to extract the username from the string:

```
var usernames = lines.Select(
    line => new String(line.Skip(32).TakeWhile(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray()));
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbMeKk)

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQ-ish solution:

```
  List<string> lines = new List<string>()
  {
      "[20:03:01 INFO]: UUID of player MyUsername123 is b87e1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8659de8b4",
      "[21:03:10 INFO]: UUID of player Cool_Username is b7ecbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652f9de8b4",
      "[22:23:10 INFO]: UUID of player theuserN4m3 is b87eabc-c67c-4026-a359-8652ad9dssdse8b4",
      "[20:08:10 INFO]: UUID of player WhatANiceUsername is b87g1cbc-c67c-4026-a359-8652agde8b4",
  };

  IEnumerable<string> players = from line in lines select line.Split(' ')[5];
```